# In place string replacement of file in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I Am trying to Read a file in linux line by line containg data something like this

```
522240227       B009CPMJ1M      20141003        20141103        1063278  1       1       6
604710621       B004NPI3OI      20141003        20141103        166431   1       1       6
1498812521      B00LFEHWJM      20141003        20141103        1044646  1       10      6
1498812521      B00D3IK0Y2      20141003        20141103        1044646  2       10      6
```

I then have to add 2000000000 to the first integer of each line and replace that integer. So final File would be like

```
2522240227       B009CPMJ1M      20141003        20141103        1063278  1       1       6
2604710621       B004NPI3OI      20141003        20141103        166431   1       1       6
31498812521      B00LFEHWJM      20141003        20141103        1044646  1       10      6
31498812521      B00D3IK0Y2      20141003        20141103        1044646  2       10      6
```

Is there i can do this operation on the same file without creating any other temporary file using shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for awk!

```
awk '{$1+=2000000000}1' file
```

It returns:

```
2522240227 B009CPMJ1M 20141003 20141103 1063278 1 1 6
2604710621 B004NPI3OI 20141003 20141103 166431 1 1 6
3498812521 B00LFEHWJM 20141003 20141103 1044646 1 10 6
3498812521 B00D3IK0Y2 20141003 20141103 1044646 2 10 6
```

It is quite explanatory: `$1+=2000000000` adds `2000000000` to the first value. Then, `1` is True, so it performs the default `awk` action: `{print $0}`, that is, print the line.

To replace the file, redirect to a temp file and then move:

```
awk '{$1+=2000000000}1' file > new_file && mv new_file file
```

---

Since it was a big number and it was printing in a e+xx format, let's fix the format with `sprintf()`:

```
awk '{$1 = sprintf("%0.f", $1+=2000000000)}1' file
```

This takes profit of the `sprintf` to store a formated value into a variable, so that then it is printed properly.

Comment: Since the first number is very large, after this command output is coming something like :1.26737e+10 B00BXNOD56 20141003 20141103 69765 1 4 6
1.26742e+10 B008O9LLN4 20141003 20141103 602348 2 2 6
1.26756e+10 B007BKFFZM 20141003 20141103 15857531 5 20 6
1.26764e+10 093794811X 20141003 20141103 173515 1 3 6
1.26764e+10 1560327146 20141003 20141103 173515 1 3 6
1.26777e+10 B00DXYNQYC 20141003 20141103 502394 1 1 6
1.26803e+10 B00IKL8VIO 20141003 20141103 495224 1 3 6

Comment: @user3034987 do you get a proper output if you say `awk '{$1+=2000000000; printf "%0.f\n", $1}' file` ??

Comment: No , In that case i only gets the first column of the file and rest of the data gets eliminated..

Comment: @user3034987 yes, true, but does it print the number properly in that case? If so, I will update using `printf` together with `%0.f`

Comment: But there is also one thing..It printed the output on the console but didn't changed the original file. Also since its a huge file ~ 20 GB , I am not preferring to print the output to another temporary file and then renaming it. Is it possible that the same file gets updated at the same time.

Comment: @user3034987 Give a try to this: `awk '{$1 = sprintf("%0.f", $1+=2000000000)}1' file`. And no, it is best to use a temp file. Even if you do it that way, it is a bit risky to overwrite a file if you are not sure if the output will be fine.